# utilizar ajax para cargar informacion

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Tengo el siguiente formulario que tiene la siguiente opción:

```
echo "<tr>";
     echo "<td class='cs'>Forma pago</td><td>";
     echo "<div id='contenedor2'>";
     echo "<select name = 'cod_tarj'  style='border-color: #FF0000 #FF0000; border-width: 2px 2px; border-style: solid solid; font-size:8pt; color: #FF0000; letter-spacing; width:150px'></select>";
   echo "</div>"; 
   echo "</td>"; 
   echo "</tr>";
```

Tiene con `id =contenedor2` el cual esta ligado a una función de javascript

```
function mostrar_formaPago()
{
            var contenedor, m; 
      contenedor = document.getElementById('contenedor2');  
      document.form1.orden.value = ''

      m = document.form1.estado.options[document.form1.estado.selectedIndex].value

      ajax=nuevoAjax(); 

      ajax.open('POST','ajax_tarjeta.php',true); 

      ajax.onreadystatechange=function() 
      { 
        if (ajax.readyState==4) { 

           contenedor.innerHTML = ajax.responseText 


        } 
      }
```

Este a su vez hace un llamado a un ajax que tiene el código y la descripción de una tarjeta:

```
$estado=$_POST['estado'];

$sql="SELECT * FROM  tarjetas WHERE sw_activo='$estado'";

$consulta=mysql_query($sql);

while($result=mysql_fetch_array($consulta)) 

{

echo "<option value = ".$result['cod_tarj'].">".$result['cod_tarj']."_".$result['desc_tarj']."</option>";
}
```

Necesito hacer que la tarjeta que cargue dependa de una lista
dependiendo de su estado `1=activas`, `2=inactiva` `3=carga todas`

```
echo "<tr>"; 

         td1S(_LBFRM1_ESTADO,estado,'mostrar_formaPago()');
          td1SOp(3,_LBFRM1_ESTADOOP3,"$estado",0);
          td1SOp(1,_LBFRM1_ESTADOOP1,"$estado",0);
          td1SOp(2,_LBFRM1_ESTADOOP2,"$estado",0);    
         td1SC(); 
 echo "</tr>";
```

Ósea si yo selecciono de la lista la 1, en el cuadro Forma Pago, solo me muestre las que están activas.

Comment: No se entiende bien, ¿puedes explicar un poco mas?

Answer (score 1):

Parece que dentro de la función mostrar_formaPago falta enviar los datos hacia el backend (hacia el procedimiento en php):

```
ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
ajax.send('estado=' + encodeURIComponent(m));
```

esto iría como últimos renglones de la función.

Comment: le hice los cambios indicados y le adicione lo que me indican  ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
      ajax.setRequestHeader('Connection','Close');
            ajax.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control','no-cache, must-revalidate');
            ajax.setRequestHeader('Expires','Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
      ajax.send('&estado='+estado);  pero me sale error 'setRequestHeader' no está definido .. cual prodria ser el error.

Answer (score 0):

## TRY

```js
function mostrar_formaPago(estado) {

    var contenedor, m;
    contenedor = document.getElementById('contenedor2');
    document.form1.orden.value = ''

    m = document.form1.estado.options[document.form1.estado.selectedIndex].value

    var data = "estado=" + estado;
    ajax = nuevoAjax();

    ajax.open('POST', 'ajax_tarjeta.php', true);

    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (ajax.readyState == 4) {

            contenedor.innerHTML = ajax.responseText


        }
        ajax.send(data);
    }
}
```